# Private registry with Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, registry

I'm trying (for tests purpose) to expose to kubernetes a very simple image pong http:

```
FROM golang:onbuild
EXPOSE 8000
```

I built the docker image:

```
docker build -t pong .
```

I started a private registry (with certificates):

```
docker run -d --restart=always --name registry -v `pwd`/certs:/certs -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key -p 443:443 registry:2.6.2
```

I created a secret:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regsecret --docker-server=localhost --docker-username=johndoe --docker-password=johndoe --docker-email=johndoe@yopmail.com
```

I uploaded the image:

```
docker tag 9c0bb659fea1 localhost/pong
docker push  localhost/pong
```

I had an insecure registry configuration

```
{
  "storage-driver" : "aufs",
  "insecure-registries" : [
    "localhost"
  ],
  "debug" : true,
  "experimental" : true
}
```

So I tried to create my kubernetes pods with:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pong
spec:
  containers:
    - name: pong
      image: localhost/pong:latest
      imagePullPolicy: Always
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: regsecret
```

I'm on MacOS with docker Version 17.12.0-ce-mac49 (21995).

If I use `image: localhost/pong:latest` I got:

```
waiting:
          message: 'rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: error
            parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character ''d'' looking for beginning
            of value: "default backend - 404"'
          reason: ErrImagePull
```

I'm stuck on it since the beginning of the week, without success.

Answer (score 1):

It was not a problem of registry configuration.
I forgot to mention that I used minikube.

For the flags to be taken into account, I had to delete the minikube configuration and recreate it

`minikube delete`

`minikube start --insecure-registry="10.0.4.0/24"`

Comment: i'm not sure if answering your own question is the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Hey try to browse your registry using this nice front end app https://hub.docker.com/r/konradkleine/docker-registry-frontend/

Perhaps this will give you some hint , it looks like the registry has some configuration issue...

Answer (score 0):

instead of deleting the cluster first (`minikube delete`) the configuration `json` may be editied at `~/.minikube/config/config.json` to add this section accordingly:

`{
...
    "HostOptions": {
            ...
            "InsecureRegistry": [
                "private.docker.registry:5000"
            ],
            ...
        },
        ...
    }
    ...
}`

this only works on started clusters, as the configuration file won't be populated otherwise. the answer above using `minikube --insecure-registry=""` is fine.